# AbuDhabi US Preclearence

Tags: usa, accommodation

At AbuDhabi Preclearence, do they ask for proof of accommodation like hotel booking?
what if i am staying with a US family as a PG, THEY DONT HAVE ANY PAPER TO PROVE THE BOOKING.

HOW can i handle such suituation

or it is a must to have hotel booking??

Comment: What does a "PG" mean here? Personal guest maybe?

Comment: What is your nationality? Are you travelling under the VWP or with a visa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The US does not care whether you stay in a hotel or with a family. They only care that you will conform to the conditions of your visa and depart the country. All you need to do is to put the address where you will stay in the US on the landing card (which for US preclearance you fill out at Abu Dhabi before going into preclearance). If you will stay at multiple places in the US, use the address where you will stay the first night.

Comment: Thank You very much.
In simple words, the CBP Officer will not call the Hotel to check you booking.. right ?